# Error when updated to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

When updated to Xcode 7, I got a bunch of errors. Clearing it all, the final one is remaining.
`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I've been searching to sort out this. There are many answers that worked for some, but none of them are working for me. Any help is Appreciated.

UPDATE: The error screenshot below

[image]

Comment: can you show ur full error code

Comment: Yeah, just make a screenshot and attach it to your post please.

Comment: Remove all third party frameworks and add it again. This resolve my issue.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. I have marked the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have FBSDK Frameworks in your project first remove 3rd party frameworks and then add again.

Comment: I have removed it all, and added again. I have some other frameworks also. Sometimes, some other framework will not be found.Previously, it was FBSDKShareKit and Bolts before that. It changes when I try some solution.

Comment: check the path of frameworks they are present in downloads or documents. Update the path properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in order.

1. Restart Xcode
2. Select Product > Clean - this will clean your project.
3. Go to Window > Projects and delete the derived data for your project. This will cause your project to reindex.
4. If all of these methods still don't work, try restarting your system, and ensure Xcode and your system are updated to the latest versions, and try one of the earlier steps again.